# List software from restricted, multiverse separately

Tags: repository

Is there an apt, apt-get or dpkg command or option that will enable me to list the installed packages into the main, restricted, universe and multiverse repositories they were installed from separately?

If not is there another way to list packages separately according to repositories?

Comment: Did you consider `apt list | grep` ?

Comment: I asked a similar question on [unix.se] a few years ago, which you may also be interested in. [How do I list installed packages with source URI, distribution and section in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183644/2465)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the latter with `aptitude` - for example

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ?section(universe))'
```

or

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ?section(universe/math))'
```

Ex.

```
$ aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ?section(multiverse))'
i   ttf-mscorefonts-installer                                               - Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts                                      
i   ubuntu-restricted-addons                                                - Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu
```